# Is an increasing union of subspaces a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let be $
V
$
vector space :

a) If we have an infinite chain of subspaces
$
{U}_{1}\mathrm{\subseteq}{U}_{2}\mathrm{\subseteq}
$

Show that $
{U}\mathrm{{=}}\mathop{\mathrm{\cup}}\limits_{{k}\mathrm{{=}}{1}}\limits^{\mathrm{\infty}}{U}_{K}
$
 is a subspace .

b) if  $
V
$
is finite dimensional show that there is a some subspace ,call it  $
{U}_{P}
$
,such that $
{U}\mathrm{{=}}{U}_{p}
$
  and hence $
{U}_{P}\mathrm{{=}}{U}_{{P}\mathrm{{+}}{1}}\mathrm{{=}}{\mathrm{....}}
$

Comment: Any ideas how to solve it ?

Comment: Really I am just thinking about the addition and the scalar multiplication

Comment: We proved before that the union of M and N is  a subspace if and only if : M $
\mathrm{\subset}
$
N or N $
\mathrm{\subset}
$
M.

Comment: Can we proved that or depend on that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)

Take any $x\in U$ and any scalar $\alpha$. Then, prove that $\alpha\cdot x$ is also in $U$.

Take $x,y\in U$ and prove that $x+y\in U$.

**Hint**:

1. $x\in U\iff \exists i\in\mathbb N: x\in U_i$
2. If $x\in U_j$, then $x\in U_k$ for all $k\geq j$.

---

b)

**Hint**:

If $A\subseteq B$ is a subspace and $\dim(A)=\dim(B)\in\mathbb N$, then $A=B$.

Comment: Thanks a lot really i just want to ask more about the second part of the question that the basis of the subspace cant be bigger than the space

Comment: @user401187 I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Sorry I think that I didn't get it .

Comment: I didn't understand the second part of the answer

Comment: @user401187 It's a hint, not an answer. The second hint, maybe, is to say try to prove the statement by contradiction.

Comment: Can you help .me more

Comment: I just think the second part of the question is clear but I can't express that .can you tell me how is the hint meaning ?

Answer (score 1):

Your title seems a bit different than the question you ask.  In general a union of subspaces is not a subspace.  For instance, take the x axis and then the y axis.  Each is a 1 dimensional subspace, but the union is not closed under addition for instance.

a) These are chains of subspaces, so the union is easy to show closure.  Let $x,y \in U$, then $x \in U_i, y \in U_j$ for some $j \leq i$. As $U_j \subseteq U_i,\ y \in U_i$. Then, $U_i$ is a subspace, so $x+y \in U_i$ and $\lambda x \in U_i$, so they are both in U.

b) Track the basis of the vector space.  Eventually you will get all of them in that union, so it will terminate.

Comment: Can you help me more for the second part